# setvalue method does not write in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a firebase database and connected to that with the following details, but `setValue` method is not writing anything. `onComplete` event is not not even called. What is the reason?

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Code base:

```
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    User user = new User("A","B","C");
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(usr.getUsername()).setValue(usr);
```

build.gradle script:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

And the main thing which gradle does not accept 11.8.0 which firebase assistant suggests . mine is :

```
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
 implementation project(':andengine:AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter')
```

and the database rules are :

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
```

Are there any settings in Firebase or Android studio?

Comment: try to change the firebase version '11.2.0'

Comment: Please provide code of your User class here .

Comment: the user class is very simple. even you assume setvalue("test") is not working

Comment: Kindly add more information about your code and preferably the code itself to avoid future downvotes.

Comment: I am actually concern about the .getUsername() method please check it what value you are returning through it.

Comment: If you use `mFirebaseDatabase.child("Test").setValue(true);`, does it write to the database? If not, the problem is not likely to be in the code, and is more likely to be with the connection to the database.

Comment: when debugging it gets the database data very well but only setvalue does not write. is there any setting in firebase. I made the database in locked mode . but changed the rules to true.

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener and log the error? Please responde with @.

Comment: @i don't know how. when i call the push mehos it gives a unique key. it shows that the connection is OK but not only writing.

Comment: after you set the value, add the complete listener and log the error. Please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I found finally the answer. Everything was OK except on my country's IP. My country is under sanction and by VPN it solved. but when disconnecing VPN it is not workinf even after compile.